# how to find the xpath of an ionic app (without the code)

Tags: ionic-framework, automation, appium

Is there a way to find the XPath of a mobile application in my phone (which I don't have access to the code) I'm using Appium for the mobile automation and the application is written in ionic

Comment: Do you mean the destination folder for the apps installed on device?

Comment: I have installed the app on my mobile using the apk. I want to find the elements(using XPaths) of the installed app. (dont have access to the code just have to use the installed app)

Comment: I think to get the real dir of an application needs a rooted mobile to access it , but for app folders directory : android/data/packagename.these folders can be seen but reel install directory of apk could not be found or accessed without root as i know.